# Is there a way I can recover a deleted repository on Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-log, gitlab-api

I deleted a repository in Gitlab from the website, and I am trying to retrieve it, is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are subscribed for GitLab Premium or higher, you **cannot** restore your project.

The documentation says that:

> From [GitLab 13.2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/220382) on [Premium](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) or higher tiers, group owners can [configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#enable-delayed-project-removal) projects within a group to be deleted after a delayed period. When enabled, actual deletion happens after number of days specified in [instance settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#default-deletion-delay).

And just by looking at the delete button, it's clear that you won't be able to restore it later on

[image]

Comment: this is a very funny behaviour - once a project is deleted, it still hangs around for several days giving 404s when clicking on any urls referring to it, but there is no way that I am aware of to get rid of it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This evolves with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#delayed-group-and-project-deletion-set-as-default) (May 2023):

> ### Delayed group and project deletion set as default
>
> To prevent accidental deletion of projects and groups, starting in GitLab 16.0, the delayed deletion feature will be turned on by default for all GitLab Ultimate and Premium customers.
>
> Self-managed users still have the option to define a deletion delay period of between 1 and 90 days, and SaaS users have a non-adjustable default retention period of 7 days.
>
> Users of Ultimate and Premium groups can still delete a group or project immediately from the group or project settings via a two-step deletion process.
>
> We believe that this change will contribute to a safer deletion process and will be beneficial in preventing accidental deletions. We’d love your feedback in issue [#396996](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/396996).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#delayed-project-deletion) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/389557).

Reminder:

> If you are on the Free tier, your projects are immediately deleted, and you will not be able to restore them.